# How are we able to identify the differential with a covector field?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have been going through Dr. Frederic Schuller's *Lectures on the Geometric Anatomy of Theoretical Physics*, in these lectures, he states that the gradient of a function is the covector field
$$df: M\to T^*M$$ that sends a point $p\in M$ to the covector $$d_pf: T_pM\to\mathcal R$$ (where $\mathcal R$ is the real numbers) defined by $$d_pf(X):= X(f).$$  In Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, he states that the differential (or push-forward) of a smooth map $F:M\to N$ is $$d_pF: T_pM\to T_{F(p)}N$$ that sends $X\in T_pM$ to $d_pF(X) \in T_{F(p)}N$ where the last function acts on $f \in C^{\infty}(N)$ to produce $$d_pF(X)(f) := X(f \circ F).$$ Lee says that we can use the differential of a smooth map $f:M\to \mathcal R$ and the fact that $$T_p\mathcal R \cong \mathcal R$$ in order to define the gradient as a covector field (Chapter 11: The differential of a function). How is it that we can do this? Why do we call the gradient a covector if it is really just a special case of the differential?

Answer (score 1):

The differential of a real-valued function is a covector *by definition*. I'll work with real-valued functions on the plane for simplicity of notation but this works with functions on manifolds. If $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ is smooth, then its partial derivatives exist and at any point $p$ the differential $df_p:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $ is a linear map which best approximates the real variation of $f$ near $p$. (Here technically the domain and codomain of the differential are tangent spaces at $p$ and $f(p)$, which we can harmlessly identify with Euclidean spaces.) So if $v = (h,k)$ is a tangent vector at $p$ (picture a displacement away from the base point $p$), the differential $df_p(v) \approx f(p + v) - f(p)$ where the error goes to $0$ faster than $||v||$ does. For calculations using partial derivatives, one can easily show that $$df_p(v) = df_p(h,k) = f_x(p)h + f_y(p)k = \begin{pmatrix} f_x(p) & f_y(p)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} h \\ k\end{pmatrix},$$ i.e., the matrix associated to the linear map or covector $df_p$ is the *row* of partial derivatives at $p$. It acts on displacements or *column* vectors via matrix multiplication. (More generally, the matrix of $df_p$ will be the Jacobian matrix of the given $f$ between two manifolds.) One can also write $df = f_x dx + f_y dy$ globally, where $x,y$ are the canonical projection maps.

The differential $df$, a *covector* field, is thus a natural object obtained directly from the smooth function $f$. On the other hand, the gradient $\nabla f$, a *vector field*, requires additional structure to define, namely one needs an inner product (Riemannian metric on manifolds). In Euclidean space, it is obvious that the formula above for computing $df_p(h,k)$ might as well have been formulated using vectors instead:

$$df_p(h,k) = f_x(p)h + f_y(p)k  = \begin{pmatrix} f_x(p) \\ f_y(p)\end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix} h \\ k\end{pmatrix} = \nabla f_p \cdot (h,k).$$

This is the formula that *defines* the gradient vector on a general manifold: if you have a smooth inner product $g_p$ on each tangent space, you define $\nabla f$ via the formula $$df_p(v) = g_p(\nabla f_p,v) \quad \forall v.$$

Abstractly, the non-degenerate bilinear form $g_p$ gives you a natural "musical" isomorphism $T_p M \to T_p^* M$ mapping $v$ to $g_p(v,-)$, so by "raising or lowering the indices using the metric tensor" as physicists would say we can treat vectors and covectors alike. One needs to be careful when the metric is non-Euclidean though: the formula for $\nabla f$ will generally not be so simple as a vector of partial derivatives.

For a simple example, consider $\Bbb R^2 - \{ 0 \}$ with polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$; then for any smooth function $f:\Bbb R^2 - \{ 0 \} \to \Bbb R$ we have the usual natural formula $$df = f_r dr + f_\theta d\theta,$$ but

$$\nabla f = f_r \partial_r + \frac1{r^2} f_\theta \partial_\theta$$

(note the extra $\frac 1{r^2}$ factor coming from the Euclidean metric in polar coordinates).

Comment: The classical gradient is a vector field, yes. But, the differential as a map between tangent spaces is not a covector field in general. Based on my understanding, the differential is only a covector field when $T_{F(p)}N \cong \mathcal R$, since by definition, a covector field is a smooth section $\sigma : M\to T^*M$, where $ T^*M$ is the cotangent bundle, and so by the definition $\sigma(p) : T_pM\to \mathcal R$ since $\sigma(p)\in T^*_pM$. The gradient I have defined above is a covector field, one obtains the classical gradient from it by using the musical isomorphism.

Comment: Lee calls what I have defined above "an analog of the classical gradient, reinterpreted in a way that makes coordinate-independent sense on a manifold." The classical gradient does not have a very good coordinate independent formulation, but the differential does.

Comment: @DanielWaters When I wrote "differential" in the first sentence I had "differential of a function" in mind since the point is to compare to the gradient (of a function). You are correct that for a vector-valued map the differential is not a covector but a family of covectors, one for each component. This is perfectly fine: if $\vec F:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, $\vec F = (f^1,\ldots, f^m)$ then $d\vec F = (df^1, \ldots, df^m)$: intuitively, a vector of covectors, or simply a matrix (the Jacobian). What you call the "gradient" in the first definition really is the differential.

Comment: It seems like we just have different names for the same thing and that's where the confusion comes in! Yes, what I call the differential is a vector field, what you call the differential is what I call the gradient, which is a covector field. My question was more about how we can identify the gradient as a special case of the differential using the isomorphism between $T_{f(p)}\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal R$. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DanielWaters The word "differential" is used in many different contexts, add in lots of different isomorphisms and it becomes very easy to get confused. Personally, I use the words "(total) derivative" for maps between general manifolds, and "differential" for the covector $df$ associated to a real-valued function $f$ on a manifold. However I would greatly warn you against a. calling some vector field a "differential", and b. calling some covector field a "gradient". This is the opposite of what is done in essentially all differential geometry books.

Comment: @DanielWaters I tried to make it clear in the last few paragraphs of my answer that the gradient is *not* a special case of the differential: it requires extra structure than just the smooth manifold structure, namely it requires a (pseudo-)Riemannian structure. However once you have a metric, it is easy to convert any covector field into a vector field and vice versa, but the transition is not as seamless as it is in Euclidean space (extra coefficients appear coming from the metric, as in the polar coordinate example).

Comment: What I call the differential is also called the push-forward. What I call the gradient is also sometimes called the differential. For instance, Spivak calls it the differential, and so does Lee.

Comment: @DanielWaters Yes, the words "push-forward", "total derivative", "differential" all generally refer to the same thing when talking about a general map between manifolds. But you really shouldn't call this the "gradient".

Comment: Yeah, I think you're probably right. It causes some confusion, especially when everyone is so used to the gradient from standard vector analysis.

Comment: @DanielWaters Exactly. The problem is that Euclidean space has so much extra structure that it's hard to tell which objects defined on it require what structure. For one, it's a vector space, so the tangent space at each point is isomorphic to the original space. But it's also an inner product space, so we kind of take for granted that we can measure distances and angles in a "natural" way without necessarily remembering that these quantities depend on a choice of inner product (and that the standard Euclidean inner product *is the same at each point* once we identify the tangent spaces) .

Comment: @DanielWaters When extending these notions to general manifolds it becomes important to understand the dependency on the extra structure. Then one realizes that one only needs a notion of smooth atlas to differentiate real-valued functions $f$ and define differentials $df$, which are covector fields. But in order to relate this to a gradient vector field (intuitively, a flow on the manifold pointing in directions where $f$ increases the fastest) one needs a metric, i.e., an idea of how to measure *distances* on the manifold as well as *curvature*.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for your input. I forgot to look at one of my best resources (Will Merry's notes on differential geometry) and it clarifies my original question. Thanks again!